# How to force unlink on attached/inserted images?

Tags: theme-development, attachments

When users insert an image into the content, WordPress automatically wraps the image in a hyperlink that, when clicked, creates an "attachment" page showing only the image inside the theme.

Can I insert a code in my theme that tells WP not to create this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert an image it becomes an attachment, whether you link to that page or not. You can simply select 'none' in the link url field when the image is inserted, it's one of the options in the media panel.